# Convert a Pandas 'DOB' column to 'Age' but it has NaT/empty values due to which it throws an error "NaTType does not support strftime"

Tags: python, pandas

I have a client's data which contains a DOB column and I want to calculate the age, but there are missing cells so it throws an error "NaTType does not support strftime". I want to populate the missing value with mean age later. Here's what I tried

```
for row in new_data['DOB']:
    if row is pd.NaT:
        continue
    else:
        new_data['DOB'] = new_data['DOB'].apply('{:06}'.format)
        now = pd.Timestamp('now')
        new_data['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(new_data['DOB'], format='%m%d%y')    
        new_data['DOB'] = new_data['DOB'].where(df['DOB'] < now, new_data['DOB'] -  np.timedelta64(100, 'Y'))
        new_data['age'] = (now - new_data['DOB']).astype('<m8[Y]')

new_data
```

Comment: Can you add some data sample of `DOB` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your `DOB` column is of `datetime` time you could do `(pd.Timestamp('now')-df.DOB)/pd.Timedelta('1Y')`.

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'DOB': pd.to_datetime('2020')-pd.to_timedelta(pd.np.random.randint(7000,20000,5), 'D')})
df.iloc[[1,3]] = None

df['age'] = (pd.Timestamp('now') - df.DOB)/pd.Timedelta('1Y')
df.age = df.age.fillna(df.age.mean()).astype(int)
```

Result:

```
         DOB  age
0 1997-02-05   23
1        NaT   25
2 1991-12-08   28
3        NaT   25
4 1995-12-30   24
```

Comment: It worked, but I didn't get why does it solve the `NaT` issue.

Comment: in the first step, `df['age'] = (pd.Timestamp('now') - df.DOB)/pd.Timedelta('1Y')` we retain NaT values (pandas takes care of this without throwing errors, it just propagates the NaT to the result), and in the second step we replace these NaTs with the average. In your code line `new_data['DOB'].apply('{:06}'.format)` you apply the function to the **whole** column (i.e. all rows) which leads to the error.